# Как создать триггер, который после добавления записи в 1 таблицу создаст n количество записей в другой таблице?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, триггер

Триггер должен работать следующим образом:

1. Осуществляется запись в таблицу (table1) подобного типа:
   SerialNumber: 123456, DeviceCount: N(n ≥ 1);
2. Должен срабатывать AFTER TRIGGER, который в таблице (table2) создаст N-количество записей указанное в DeviceCount. Пример:

```
------------ INSERT Table1 --------------
SerialNumber: 123456, DeviceCount: 3;
---------- Trigger INSERT Table2 --------
SerialNumber: 123456, DeviceNumber: 1;
SerialNumber: 123456, DeviceNumber: 2;
SerialNumber: 123456, DeviceNumber: 3;
-----------------END---------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO table2 (SerialNumber, DeviceNumber)
SELECT NEW.SerialNumber, series.DeviceNumber 
FROM generate_series(1, NEW.DeviceCount) AS series(DeviceNumber);
```